# Is it possible to move a comment in Word?

Tags: comments, microsoft-word-2016

There is a comment on a picture in a Word document. Now I want to update the picture, but keep the comment. So I have to move the comment from the picture to a text.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Issue: I want be able to move comments. If I select the image with the comment and press the delete key, the comment will be also removed. Now I found a little trick so that the comment remains with the picture. But is there an option to attach the comment to another place (text, image, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate this and I've just tried.

I have an image in my Word file (insert -> Picture), and a comment "attached" to it.

I've changed the image etc and the comment remains.

Instead of deleting the image, right click on it and choose `update image`

Comment: I also tried that now. It works if you 1. Select the old image 2. Paste the new image 3. Delete the old image. But if you delete the image first, the comment is also deleted. Can a comment be moved?

Comment: @testing, I've updated my post

Comment: Is it possible to move comments in general?

Comment: @testing - Only If you move the block of text, image, ect that the comment is attached to.

Comment: @Ramhound: Thanks for your addition. You also have the option to e.g. change the text, where the comment is attached to. But it would be nice if you also could move the comment by editing the comment or something like this.

Comment: I assume you are trying to avoiding adding a new comment to the document for reasons of document control, but the thing is, the comment moving and it being a new comment is basically the same thing to most forms of document control.  So just copy the text and create a new comment.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yeah, that's true. But I wanted to keep the author/date of the comment :-)